# Strange segmentation fault when reaching for-loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, assembly, segmentation-fault

I have some C++ code that is being called by an Assembly module. My code is supposed to sort an array by pointers.

My two issues reside in the second `for-loop`:

- I comment out the couts and the program immediately segfaults when it approaches the second `for-loop` in my code, not the first one that just outputs the array. I am able to see the output of the first `for-loop`.
- I do not comment out the couts and the `for-loop` runs then segfaults when it has to increment `i`. I am able to see all the outputs this `for-loop` makes.

---

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void swapASM(double (**address));

extern "C" void sortbypointers(double *arr[], long size)
{
    cout << "Before sort: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << (*(arr[i])) << " ";
    }

    // problems starts here
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "i: " << i;
        for(int j = i+1; i <= size; j++)
        {
            if((*(arr[i])) > (*(arr[j])))
            {
                //cout << endl << "Before swap: \ni: " << i << "\narr[i]: " << *(arr[i]) << "\nj: " << j << "\narr[j]: " << *(arr[j]) << endl;
                swapASM(&(arr[i]));
                //cout << endl << "After swap: \ni: " << i << "\narr[i]: " << *(arr[i]) << "\nj: " << j << "\narr[j]: " << *(arr[j]) << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "After sort: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(arr[i]) << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << "Return" << endl;
    return;

}
```

Comment: I believe your inner `for-loop` will increment past `size`. Try `size - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int j = i+1; i <= size; j++;
```

I think this is causing the problem.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. How embarrassing for someone who has been coding for quite sometime now. It works. Thanks.

Comment: The site makes me wait ten minutes before accepting an answer.